# The usage of "think" followed by an object and an objective complement

Tags: grammar

If you can say "I think him a great man.", can you also say "I think him great."?

Comment: You can't say either of those sentences as far as I know. Do you have a reference for them?

Comment: @neeku you can absolutely say those sentences, though it's a rather old-fashioned phrasing.

Answer (score 2):

Both those sentences are correct (if a bit old-fashioned). However, they *don't* convey the same meaning, simply because **He's great.** does not convey the same meaning as **He's a great man.**

> **He's great**

This is an informal/colloquial construction which implies ***wonderful; first-rate; very good.***

> **He's a great man**

This, on the other hand, implies ***a person who has achieved importance or distinction in a field.***

One might say, *"John always helps me out with my homework. He's great!"* And it would be perfectly okay, because it would convey that the speaker thinks John is wonderful for helping him out.

But if one was to say that *"John is a great man"*, it would imply he has done something important or impressive - helping one with homework wouldn't be enough!

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Most common is "I think that he is a great man", less so is "I think him a great man", least common is "I think him great."